# Uploading File to a specific Directory through phpseclib

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpseclib

Hi I am facing a problem while uploading a file to a folder, My Code is following:

```
set_time_limit(0);
include('Net/SFTP.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('key/key.pem'));
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com');
if (!$sftp->login('root', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
else{
    echo'Login Successfull';
}
echo '<br>';
print_r($sftp->nlist($sftp->chdir("new_folder")));
echo '<br>';
$sftp->put('file.txt', 'hello, world!');
```

The problem is that even after changing the directory to new_folder. it is putting the file inside root folder. Any help would be highly appreciable.
output of nlist

```
Array ( [0] => etc [1] => selinux [2] => srv [3] => dev [4] => boot [5] => smnt [6] => sbin [7] => image [8] => opt [9] => var [10] => . [11] => tmp [12] => sys [13] => new_folder [14] => lost+found [15] => .. [16] => .kconfig [17] => mnt [18] => lib [19] => root [20] => .profile [21] => lib64 [22] => home [23] => proc [24] => isa_home [25] => bin [26] => usr )
```

Comment: Are you sure that `new_folder` exists? Btw, the return value of `chdir()` is a boolean, so using that as the first argument to `nlist()` may not work the way you think it does.

Comment: new_folder is just an example i have put in this question originally it is something different.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `->chdir()`? If it's `false`, it didn't change the directory.

Comment: Yeah it changed the directory but again for next command it reverted back to /root folder

Comment: It's weird that your `print_r` outputted anything at all. When I tried to do it the way you're doing it it didn't do anything. It should try to show you the contents of `/root/1` (since `chdir` is presumably returning a `true`, which is being cast to a `'1'`). Since `/root/1` doesn't exist, per your `print_r`, you shouldn't be getting any output. And the output you are getting looks more like what I'd expect to see in `/` and not `/root/`. Anyway, try enabling logging. eg. `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', 3);` If you could then add the results of that to your orig. post that'd be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone i had solved this issue using following code:

```
$success_t = $sftp->put($remote_directory . $temps_file,$local_directory . $temps_file);
```